# How to authenticate https client certificates using Dancer/Starman or Mojolicious/Daemon?

Tags: perl, ssl, dancer

I am trying to perform Authentication using HTTPS client certificates using perl Dancer framework.
I would like to accept requests sent with/without certificate and do validation on the certificate CN to proceed with the valid response
(https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326, the link shows how to do it in node.js, need something very similar for perl Dancer/Starman/Plackup)

I have setup ssl using Dancer/Plackup, but have not found a way to get details about the peer certificate to perform validation in Dancer framework

I would like to achieve the following:

If the request is sent

without certificate => 401

with certificate but client has self-signed (CN doesn't match with server cert CN) => 401

with certificate but client cert has been signed using server cert (CN matches server cert CN) => 200

Comment: If you have a solution that's different please add it as an answer instead of editing it in to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Dancer you can get the IO::Socket::SSL object with `request->env->{'psgix.io'}`, but that does not help you because you have no opportunity to configure it for client verification. IO::Socket::SSL::set_defaults does not run early enough, either.

This means it's best to set up [Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#var_ssl_client_verify) to terminate TLS. Pass on the certificate info you need (e.g. client verification result) in environment variables to the Dancer application.

Comment: yeah, would need to utilize server abilities to do the validation, worked around it and managed to get the details in the application

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who is facing the issue, I solved it by the following steps:
(To create client and server certificates, I followed https://medium.com/@sevcsik/authentication-using-https-client-certificates-3c9d270e8326)

1) Use nginx (Setup guide:https://gist.github.com/netpoetica/5879685)

2) Create the nginx config

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /to/path/server_cert.pem;  # server certificate
    ssl_certificate_key /to/path/server_key.pem; # server key

    ssl_client_certificate /to/path/server_cert.pem; # client CA => server certificate for self signed 
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header SSL_CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_cert; #ENTIRE CLIENT CERTIFICATE
        proxy_set_header SSL_CLIENT_S_DN $ssl_client_s_dn; #SUBJECT DN
        proxy_set_header SSL_CLIENT_I_DN $ssl_client_i_dn; #ISSUER DN
    }
}
```

More details regarding ssl can be shared using the attributes mentioned on http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables

3) Dancer application

```
get '/' => sub {
    info to_dumper(request->headers);
    content_type 'text/xml';
    return "OK";
};
```

4) Start the dancer application using plackup (or starman/your preferred choice)

```
carton exec plackup -R /bin,/lib bin/app.psgi
```

5) Send the request to the server

```
curl -v https://localhost/ --key client_key.pem --cert client_cert.pem --cacert server_cert.pem
```

6) You should observe client certificate details in the plackup logs